# potgresql uses only one worker for index creation

Tags: postgresql, index

To speed up the `CREATE INDEX` operation I increased the `work_mem` and set `max_parallel_maintenance_workers` to 8 and it worked as expected when I was creating a `B-tree` index on the table. I saw 7 parallel workers apart from the main one. But when I started to create a `Hash` index on the same table I saw that there was only 1 cpu core used by the only worker.

Are there some special options that I should change to gain the same result as when I was creating a b-tree index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  No one has implemented parallel build for hash indexes.

See [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createindex.html):

> For index methods that support building indexes in parallel (currently, only B-tree)

So you would need to implement it before you could use it.